# How to get Aliseeks api key? And how to log in to Aliseeks?

Tags: api

I'm trying to get an API key for Aliseeks.
I've created an account on AliExpress but I can't log in to Aliseeks.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can login Aliseeks from below link

https://www.aliseeks.com/ap/login

And you will get landing page where you can find API key Please check the screenshot.

[image]